# How to use a python package - shouldn't i be able to access anything listed in __all__?

Tags: python, module, package, upnp

I'm trying to use the pyupnp package (http://code.google.com/p/pyupnp/)

I've built and installed it and in my code I have:

```
import pyupnp
b = pyupnp.UpnpBase()
...
```

But I get this error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'UpnpBase'

Now I had a look in the code for the package, and it has the following:

```
__all__ = [
  'UpnpNamespace',
  'UpnpDevice',
  'UpnpBase',
  ...
```

I thought that I would be able to access anything in the `__all__` list? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at this package, you should import `pyupnp.upnp`, not `pyupnp`. The contents of `__all__` are irrelevant here.

Comment: As a further explanation -- the contents of `__all__` are not checked against names defined in the module when the module is imported. Rather, it's a filter against those names, when used in the form `from some_module import *` -- that will only import things listed in `__all__`, but not necessarily everything there. I often find my `__all__`s get out of date when I refactor and forget to update them.